# AngularJS: Mapping check box to an array

Tags: angularjs

I currently have checkboxes that the user can choose between which then are sent to my model,

```
<div ng-repeat="option in roleOptions">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{option.Id}}" ng-model="user.Roles[option.Id]">{{option.Name}}
</div>
```

The problem is that this produces a result like this,

```
{
  0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'c'
}
```

Whereas I want an output like this,

```
['a','b','c']
```

I realise that I could just convert them after, but I'd really like to change my html in some way so that it maps straight to an array, because I will also be sending this data in an array format to the html as well so I don't want to have to keep converting all the time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

ng-model *only works* on an object. You are trying to push a value onto an array. You are probably best of using ng-click and creating your own handler to push / shift from the array.

```
<div ng-repeat="option in roleOptions">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{option.Id}}" ng-click="addToArray(user.Roles, option.Id)">{{option.Name}}
</div>
```

Comment: OK thanks. I guess I'll have to do it the awkward way and convert it back and forth.

Comment: Shouldn't be that awkward. Just create a function which add/removes values from the array you are using. No more fuzz needed :)

Comment: @user3407039 If this answer was satisfactory, please accept it.